# Guidance on creating an instance for a class with boolean

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm currently trying to create an instance from a different file and the class has a boolean. I've tried calling it a couple different ways, but I'm unable to get the results I'm seeking. This is how the class starts below:

```
 public boolean buyFunction(int balance, double amountSpent)
```

Here's one of the instances I've tried creating

```
boolean buyFunction buy = buyFunction();
```

I just get the error message

```
error: ';' expected
        boolean buyFunction buy = buyFunction();
```

Comment: try ``boolean buy = buyFunction();``

Comment: I get the error `error: method buyFunction in class StockClient cannot be applied to given types;`

Comment: You need to add an int for the balance and a double for the amountSpent.

Comment: @NewbieTing check my answer

Comment: @beastlyCoder I just tried your method and it worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: @NewbieTing awesome! Make sure you accept the answer :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `buyFunction(int balance, double amountSpent)` is a method, not a class. Secondly:

```
boolean buyFunction buy = buyFunction();
```

Looks like it has two names, which a variable can't have. Also, when you called the method, you did not pass in an int, and a double. Also, to call the method without an instance of a class, you'd have to instantiate the object.

Here is something that could work:

```
YourClassName y = new YourClassName();

boolean buy = y.buyFunction(500, 45.50);
```

Now if you don't want to make an object, and just call the function, you could make use the `static` keyword:

```
 public static boolean buyFunction(int balance, double amountSpent)
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
boolean buy = buyFunction(500, 45.50);
```

This would pass 500 to the balance parameter, and 45.50 to the amountSpent parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are not instantiating the class beforehand. Depending on the name of the class that the function `buyFunction` is in, you would first need to instantiate the class, and then use that instance to get the boolean. Assuming the class name is `Test` (though this is probably different for you), you would do:

```
Temp val = new Temp();
boolean buy = val.buyFunction(int <theIntYouWant>, double <theDoubleYouWant);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean buyFunction buy = buyFunction();
```

This line has several syntax problems. First of all, to declare a variable you specify the type and the name:

```
boolean buy;
```

when you do `boolean buyFunction buy`, it confuses the compiler because `buyFunction` looks like a variable name and the `buy` after it is unexpected. This is the immediate cause of the error.

Here you also want to initialize the value of the variable `buy`. You can do this like so:

```
boolean buy = buyFunction();
```

Now the problem is that `buyFunction()` expects two parameters:

```
public boolean buyFunction(int balance, double amountSpent)
```

The first is an `int` type that represents the balance and the second is a `double` which represents the `amountSpent`. If you don't know what `int` and `double` mean, I suggest you read some more Java tutorials about data types.

So for example, you can do something like this:

```
boolean buy = buyFunction(500, 2.50);
```

I don't know what the exact values you pass for the arguments here. They might come from other variables in your code. You will have to figure this part out yourself since your question doesn't have enough information for me to make any further suggestions.